# Looking for a jquery data grid with cell formatting

Tags: jquery, grid

I am looking for an open source jquery data grid (read-only is fine) with **cell** (not row) formatting.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, I think I will be using [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) - it is very powerful and flexible.

There is a custom formatter function that you can use to format a column. I'm not sure what your criteria is for formatting the cell, but technically you could use if/else structures inside that function to only format based on certain values...

To format the cells, use the [cell formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter)

Answer (score 0):

I've used the jquery tablesorter with great success, [it does provide a hook to get into the cell and format it](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-option-text-extraction.html)